# Overt verb meaning "to look at affectionately"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What is a verb meaning "to look at affectionately" in a way that is distinctly visible in the subject's facial expression? For example in

> Alice beams at Bob.

the action is visually and emotionally evocative. (However I think "beams at" mostly connotes approval.) Also, this should be appropriate for a parent-child
relationship.

Comment: After reading more about ELL, I think this should be moved to English SE.

Comment: Andy: As you wish....

Comment: "To gaze benevolently or lovingly" ?

Comment: I was looking for a single word. Perhaps "gaze" is the closest in all of English.

Comment: "Gazed upon" could definitely work. It seems to convey a measure of adoration or reverence, particularly if you attach some appropriate adjective to the object of the gaze. I.e., "gazed upon his heroic visage" or some such.

Answer (score 1):

**Gaze** means "to look steadily, intently, and with fixed attention."[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaze)

In one sense, it is a term popularized by psychoanalyst Jacques Lacan for the anxious state that comes with the awareness that one can be viewed. The psychological effect, Lacan argues, is that the subject loses a degree of autonomy upon realizing that he or she is a visible object.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaze

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the word DOTE usually followed by the preposition on/upon
to mean " shower some one with love and excessive affection."

It is the German origin and excessive fondness which go to mean " act in a 
foolish manner" as King Lear's 'senile dotage'— the other meaning of 'dote'. However the word is often used without the foolish overtone.

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives:

[**moon over**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/moon-over)
*to spend time thinking about someone who you are attracted to instead of doing anything useful*
http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/moon-over

[**admire**](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/admire)
*to regard with wonder, pleasure, or approval.*
http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/admire

[**idolize**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/idolize)
*to regard with blind adoration, devotion, etc.*
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/idolize